# not sure how to write this Excel if else statement

Tags: excel

Ive never used excel for this and am not sure how to write this if statement

If [A1]>[B1],then [C1] else B1 I cant get it and i just need top get this done so I can get back to my real job that does use excel.

Answer (score 2):

=if(a1>b1, c1, b1)

Should work, excel formats it this way:
=if(logical_test, true, false)

If this is for an entire column of a and b, but the C value is constant, push F4 when selecting that box

Comment: what example? You should add the example to the original question.